# Close SQL Connection on Form Close (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, forms, db2

I created a small application that queries a db2 database and returns information. I created a windows form that accepts input and returns the information from the query. My closing statement is a:

`finally
  {
     conn.close();
  }`

I was curious -- does the connection (conn) actually close when I hit the little red box on the form? I searched the other questions here and the web but could not really find a definitive answer.

Here's the full try-catch-finally block (with some info obfuscated --> *****):

`try
            {

```
            conn.Open();
            string queryString = String.Format("SELECT * " +
                                                "FROM ***** " +
                                                "WHERE USERPRF LIKE '%{0}%' " +
                                                "ORDER BY TIMESTMP DESC " +
                                                "FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY", userNameInput);

            using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(queryString, conn))
            {
                using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string ***** = reader["*****"].ToString();
                        string ***** = reader["*****"].ToString();
                        string user = reader["USERPRF"].ToString();
                        string timeStamp = reader["TIMESTMP"].ToString();

                        listBox1.Items.Clear();

                        listBox1.Items.Add("Username: " + user);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("*****" + *****);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("*****: " + *****);
                        listBox1.Items.Add("Last Changed: " + timeStamp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Clear();
                        listBox1.Items.Add("There was no data to return! Try again.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }`
```

Comment: If your app is a single form only app, and you close your app, the conn will definitly not remain open. But you showed as a part of a try catch block, so we would need to see the complete try catch to tell you what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the connection is owned by the application, then yes - it should close.
It is generally bad practice to leave a connection open for long duration's as it constitutes a security risk. (Someone could inject code into your application to reuse the open the connection, to do dodgy stuff)

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnectString))
{
    // Stuff
}
```

I would make sure that you handle the onClosing event of your windows form, and tell it to dispose of the SqlConnection explicitly, or at least attempt to do so.
Better safe than sorry.

Note - I have heard some talk that SqlConnections can be shared in the SQLConnectionPool. If this is the case, you can modify your connection string to disable or enable ConnectionPooling.

Comment: That is very enlightening, thanks for that! I will take a look at SQLConnectionPool -- I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: You should also consider the audience of your application.
If you are distributing the application to many people, then definitely do not have direct database access within the application. Instead use a web service and gateway approach. 
If this application is going to be on a secure server that no one can get at, then yes - you should be safe to use direct database access. I would still recommend keeping your SQL Connections short and concise. When finished using the database, disconnect, when you need to connect again - reconnect.